# Rails 7 flash message partially hidden

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 7 app I'm using Devise to login/register. When the user has not filled in the email or password field I display a flash message: `You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.`. The thing is I don't know why this message is partly hidden on mobile view:

[image]

Here is the div container:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show position-absolute start-50 translate-middle-x" role="alert" style="top: 5px">
    You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
```

How to fully expose this flash message?

Comment: Have you tried z-index CSS directives ?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/z-index/

Comment: I've tried to all of the z-index's but non of them work

Comment: Maybe another z-index is above the alert's one ?

Comment: Nah, also tried to wrapped everything into another div with z-index but that doesn't work too. If I change position-absolute to something different e.g. position-flex I'll have something like this https://imgur.com/a/Y7MD1BX